# Swift get tableview array count and place it textview

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, uitableview

Hello i have tableview and parsing json and i have textview, i want to add my tableview items count into textview but gives me ;

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Error

My codes here

```
var clientList = [String]()

let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSArray

            if let parseJSON = json {

                self.clientList = parseJSON as! [String]
                self.clientsmessage.text = "You have \(self.clientList.count) client"

            }
```

Comment: So your text view isn't loaded?

Comment: @Wain yeah gives that error

Comment: If your `clientsmessage.text = "..."` gives error, can you check your `clientsmessage` initialization?

Comment: @Breek yeah worked add answer i will apply it Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `self.clientsmessage` doesn't instantiate correctly, please check the part.

**OR**

```
if self.clientsmessage != nil {
    self.clientsmessage.text = "You have \(self.clientList.count) client"
}
```